# Which Perl module both parses and writes XML, strictly obeying node order?

Tags: xml, perl

When using XML to annotate text rather than as a semi-structured database language, node order is very important. For instance, in this example, inodes could be phrases and leaves, tokens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root>
    <inode>
        <leaf id="a"/>
    </inode>
    <leaf id="b"/>
    <inode>
        <leaf id="c"/>
    </inode>
    <leaf id="d"/>
</root>
```

I am used to [`XML::TreePP`](http://search.cpan.org/~kawasaki/XML-TreePP-0.42/lib/XML/TreePP.pm), but when parsing an example like this, even using `Tie::IxHash`, it will create two list references `$xml->{'root'}{'inode'}` and `$xml->{'root'}{'leaf'}`, meaning if I try to write it again I will obtain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <inode>
        <leaf id="a" />
    </inode>
    <inode>
        <leaf id="c" />
    </inode>
    <leaf id="b" />
    <leaf id="d" />
</root>
```

Is anyone aware of a Perl module that makes it possible to parse a string representing XML markup, make some modifications on it, and write that back as a string, all the while scrupulously obeying the order of the original? For it to be pure-Perl is not absolutely required, although it is preferred.

Comment: [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) has a standard [DOM interface](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), which is necessarily node-order aware. Anyway, tool recommendations are off topic on SO.

Comment: Having to feed XML configuration to some primitive black-box, I had a similar issue. `XML::Smart` was not too bad to write the same as read.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, and sorry @amon, I wasn't aware of that--it seemed to make sense to ask here, given the number of available modules that don't clearly document their capabilities and the (presumed) recurrence of this problem. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @scozy Please don't delete the question. It's *my* opinion that the question is off topic, but *others* may see it differently. Either way, you can [edit] your question so that it becomes a better fit. The [help/on-topic] has some resources on that, and there's also some discussion on [what exactly a recommendation question is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/229223). I must admit that your question is fairly borderline and may actually be ok.

Comment: The answer would be pretty much all of them except `XML::TreePP` and `XML::Simple`. `XML::LibXML` and `XML::Twig` are recommended.